# iOS: How to change an UIImageView by pressing a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

I have an UIImageView and an UIButton in my app. What I want to do is that when the user taps the UIButton, the UIImageView will change to another image and then almost instantly go back to the original image. To simulate an animation.

The code:

file.h

```
{

IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
IBOutlet UIButton *button;

}

-(IBAction)button:(id)sender;
```

file.m

```
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender{


}
```

What do I have to implement in both files to make this happen?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

Insert the following code inside "-(IBAction)button:(id)sender":

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                 animations:^{

                     image1.alpha = 0.1f;

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"]; // @"image2.png"

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                                      animations:^{

                                          image1.alpha = 1.0f;

                                      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                          image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];

                                      }];

                 }];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but when a I press the button sometimes it does the animation and sometimes it doesn't. At first I thought it was because the animation was going to fast, so I made it a little bit slower but it didn't do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably you need to work with alpha property of UIImageView to make things more clear. Check out the answer again, I will edit a bit.

Comment: It did work! thank you very much! the only problem is that the image dissolves, then reappears and then makes the animation. But I will do some research on how to fix that. And again, thank you!